Random Forest model - Impact of simulated bias
As part of a demonstration project, we are doing simulations using the IBM attrition data (Made-up data available from Kaggle among other places). The aim is to demonstrate two effects -

The effect of additional random noise on prediction as measured by the area under the curve, for training and test datasets. Green is the outcome given in the original dataset, and is the same for every model.



The effect of additional bias (shifted towards a positive result) on predictions.


Each boxplot comes from 1,000 simulations of a random forest using the R function ranger. Each is based on the predictions on Training or Test data, with a given level of random noise or bias added, compared with the 'true' outcome (Attrition) or the Noisy/Biassed outcome.
So the questions

The effect of noise is more or less what I expected, and I believe that that the better results for predicting the 'true' outcome (that given in the dataset) reflects the lower variability in the 'true' outcome, compared with the 'noisy' outcome. Can anyone correct me, or refer me to a discussion of this point in the literature.

The effect of bias is not what I expected. Given  that the bias modeled here, which has a stronger effect as the value of the variable DistanceFromHome increases, can only increase the number of positive outcomes, I had expected worse predictions for the 'true' value, than the biassed value. I don't see why adding a positive bias can affect the results on the test datasets in this way. Note that this bias variable is in the prediction sets, but that I get qualitatively similar results with bias variables with lower, and almost zero importance. Thoughts or references are very welcome.


